# Select statement defined by parameter SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL is there a way to grab the information in a table, but with the table name being specified by a function parameter?

Obviously the following doesn't work, but something along these lines maybe:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_table(table_name TEXT)
RETURNS TABLE (
    "ID" TEXT
) AS
$$
SELECT * FROM uploads.<table_name>
$$
LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

I'm a bit of a rookie when it comes to SQL, so would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: I even don't want to know why you need this, but in general it can be done via dynamic-sql

Comment: You cannot return a result set from a function..only 1 scalar value can be returned. If you explain what you are trying to achieve someone may be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: Are you sure you are using mysql? Returns table exists in oracle but not mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Any use of a variable in a query will be as if you had used a string literal, not an identifier.

To use a variable as an identifier, you would have to use dynamic SQL. That is, do string-concatenation of the `table_name` variable into a string which is your SELECT query, then [PREPARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html) and [EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execute.html) that query.

But https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html says:

> SQL syntax for prepared statements can be used within stored procedures, but not in stored functions or triggers.

This is because if a stored function is running, then by definition, your thread is already running a query. MySQL cannot do that.

You can write your function to do a large [CASE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) to do a different fixed query depending on the input variable.

But as P.Salmon comments above, in MySQL you can't return a table from a stored function. Functions can only return a single scalar value, not a result set. So your SELECT would need to query one column and use `INTO` syntax to save it to a variable. Then return that variable.

Also current versions of MySQL have no "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION" option. You can "CREATE FUNCTION."

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION select_table(table_name TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE result TEXT;
  CASE table_name
  WHEN 'mytable1' THEN SELECT col1 INTO result FROM mytable1;
  WHEN 'mytable2' THEN SELECT col1 INTO result FROM mytable2;
  WHEN 'mytable3' THEN SELECT col1 INTO result FROM mytable3;
  END CASE;
  RETURN result;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```